# hibernate post initialization

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I would like to initialize class members of a persisted object as soon as Hibernate loads the object from the database.

How can I do this ?

More specifically: In the following persisted object, I would like to initialize `date`'s timezone

```
class Schedule {

    Calendar date
    TimeZone tz;

}
```

I cant do this in the constructor because hibernate will use setters to initialize the object. I cant do this in the setters because I cannot rely on the order of initialization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to register a post-load event listener; it will be called after your object is loaded so you can do whatever post-processing is necessary.

If you're using JPA (Hibernate EntityManager), you can simply [write a method and annotate it with `@PostLoad`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/listeners.html).

Otherwise, for core Hibernate you'll need to implement a [PostLoadEventListener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/event/PostLoadEventListener.html) and [declare it in your configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-events).

Comment: Links are broken now, use [PostLoadEventListener](https://web.archive.org/web/20110322110535/http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/event/PostLoadEventListener.html) and [configuration](https://web.archive.org/web/20100323043415/http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/events.html)

Answer (score -1):

What is the actual scenario? If you don't need this values to be persisted, annotate them with `@Transient`, and put the initalization this way:

```
private Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Answer (score -1):

From your question I am not sure if this applies to your problem but it may be worth to take a look at  user defined types to deal with different Time zones.

This is very useful if the database should contain all timestamps in e.g. UTC time but java is using the default system timezone.

See [this article](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeForNon-defaultTimeZone)